# ng-check="true" not working when radio choices update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 columns of radio drop down boxes. I have logic where if a user selects a radio button in column 1, the radio buttons in column 2 will refresh with a new list. I always want the top radio button `all` to default to check on each new refresh of a new list in column 2. However, on a second new refresh the `ng-check="true"` will not apply and `all` will not be checked.

How can I make `all` default to checked when the list of radio buttons refresh with a new list?

```
  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Market</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <div ng-show="markets.length >= 1">
        <input type="radio" value="all" name="marketRadio" ng-checked="true" class="resetAll"
          ng-model="filter.market" ng-change="radioMap('market')">All
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="choice in markets| orderBy: 'name'">
        <input type="radio" value="{{choice.name}}" name="marketRadio"
          ng-change="radioMap('market', $index)" ng-model="filter.market" >
        {{choice.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Logic when second column of radio buttons refresh with new list:

```
  var ppvFilter = {
    regions: [],
    markets: [],
    dealers: []
  };


  function populateMarkets(regionCode) {
    ppvFilter.markets.length = 0;
    ppvFilter.dealers.length = 0;
    var urlPath = API_BASE_URI + 'service/org/' +
      regionCode + "/markets";

    var params = {
      url: urlPath,
      method: 'GET'
    };

    $http(params)
      .then(function(response) {
        ppvFilter.markets = ppvFilter.markets.concat(response.data);
      })
      .catch(failure);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ng-checked` attribute in this case is being overridden by the value of the `ng-model` you have bound to that input. If you need to set it on page load, you could use `ng-init="filter.market = true"` to set `filter.market` to be truthy, which will check the box.

In general, if you have an `ng-model` bound to an input of any kind, the model will take priority over any hardcoded attributes that attempt to set that value. You need to programmatically set `filter.market` to be true for it to work.

Comment: the refresh isn't done on a page load, though. it's real time when the user selects a radio button in the previous column of radio buttons. It's like a hierarchy. example, if user selects radio a in column 1, populate radio buttons in column 2 with these radio buttons. hence, on the SECOND update to the list.

Comment: If you could provide a plunker, I can help you debug it. But the important thing here is that the `ng-model` will always override your `ng-checked` directive. It sounds like you will need to update the `ng-model` in your controller after you receive the response from the $http request.

Comment: But that doesn't change Ethan's point. ng-checked is irrelevant because the state of the radio button is controlled by the ng-model. If you want to change the state of the button, you need to change the model.